# Why is this fade out not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am simply adding this to an inner html document. So it only want this particular item to live for 10 seconds. others are made just like it because they represent different chat bubbles.

```
function placeChatBubbleOnScreen(message){
    var chatBubble = "<div class= 'glass' onshow = '$(this).fadeOut(1000);'><p class= 'chat'>" + message + "<p></div>";
    //<img class = 'speechBubble' src = '../images/GibberChatBubble.png'/>
    document.getElementById("MenuBackground").innerHTML += chatBubble;
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Here is my whole function, it works, but the onshow jquery method isnt working

Comment: You are adding an `onshow` **HTML attribute**. Such an attribute does not exist. HTML != jQuery.

Comment: Meant `onload` maybe ?

Comment: @CyrilDD: That has no effect on `div`s.

Comment: This is also incorrect HTML: `class= 'glass'` - It has to be without spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged jQuery in your question, I'm going to put some jQuery in here.

As shown in the comments on your question, there is no onshow attribute defined, meaning it will not do anything by itself. You can still add one, but it won't be associated with any sort of event listener. You're better off using .fadeOut() from jQuery than trying to associate a listener to when it becomes visible.

Here's a good jQuery way to write what you're trying to do:

```
function placeChatBubbleOnScreen(message){
  var thisDiv = $('<div>').addClass('glass').append(
    $('<p>').addClass('chat').append(message)
  ).appendTo('#MenuBackground');

  setTimeout(function(){thisDiv.fadeOut('slow');}, 2000);
}
```

If you don't know much jQuery this can be confusing, so I'm hoping you know the basics. Here, I create a new DIV on the fly (the jQuery method [$], when passed an open tag for an element will create a new jQuery object representing that element), add the class glass to the DIV, and append a paragraph with the class chat and the text that was passed to the placeChatBubbleOnScreen method. After the DIV is created, and the paragraph appended with the message, I append the DIV to the element with ID MenuBackground. I then set a timeout so the message will remain on screen for 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds), then it will perform a fade out slowly.

Of course there are tons of different ways to do it, as with most things in coding, but this way works, and is decently concise. You can see a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jy0znq0c/

Comment: ooooooooohhhhhhhhh! that makes so much sense! Yeah I am very new to jQuery, that helped a ton! It should have been obvious tha tI should just just have updated the menubackground. Thanks a ton!